# Evaluate bigrams while creating corpus using NLTK doesn't work

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently using NLTK to create a custom corpus to perform sentiment analysis on Twitter messages.

My corpus exists of positive and negative tweets. I gave the concerning folder the same structure as the original 'movie_reviews' folder: it's called *my_movies_reviews25K* with subfolders pos & neg, each containing 25K textfiles with 1 pos or neg tweet.

Now when I'm constructing and evaluating this custom corpus, it works perfectly, with this code:

```
#this code creates corpora of my own pos/neg tweets. 
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import collections

root_folder = 'C:\Users\gerbuiker\Desktop\my_movie_reviews25K'
movie_reviews = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(root_folder, r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern='(\w+)')
movie_reviews.categories()

# define the split of % training / % test
SPLIT = 0.8

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')
negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

cutoff = int(len(posfeats) * SPLIT)

trainfeats = negfeats[:cutoff] + posfeats[:cutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[cutoff:] + posfeats[cutoff:]

print 'Train on %d instances\nTest on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats),len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print 'Accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)

classifier.show_most_informative_features()


refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testfeats):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)

print 'pos precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'pos recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'pos F-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'neg precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
print 'neg recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
print 'neg F-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
```

with output:

```
Train on 40000 instances
Test on 10000 instances
Accuracy: 0.7449
Most Informative Features
            followfriday = True              pos : neg    =    161.0 : 1.0
                  bummed = True              neg : pos    =     27.7 : 1.0
                  female = True              neg : pos    =     22.2 : 1.0
                   hurts = True              neg : pos    =     20.5 : 1.0
                anywhere = True              neg : pos    =     19.7 : 1.0
                 snowing = True              neg : pos    =     19.0 : 1.0
                      ff = True              pos : neg    =     18.1 : 1.0
                  throat = True              neg : pos    =     17.2 : 1.0
                 hurting = True              neg : pos    =     17.0 : 1.0
                   essay = True              neg : pos    =     16.6 : 1.0
pos precision: 0.831393775372
pos recall: 0.6144
pos F-measure: 0.706612995975
neg precision: 0.694210943695
neg recall: 0.8754
neg F-measure: 0.77434763379
```

In order to improve accuracy, I want to include bigrams. I use the following code for that:

```
#this code creates corpora of my own pos/neg tweets. Includes bigrams
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
import collections, itertools
import nltk.classify.util, nltk.metrics
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews, stopwords
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.probability import FreqDist, ConditionalFreqDist


root_folder = 'C:\Users\gerbuiker\Desktop\Sentiment Analyse\my_movie_reviews25K'
movie_reviews = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(root_folder, r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern='(\w+)')
movie_reviews.categories()

def evaluate_classifier(featx):
    negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
    posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

    negfeats = [(featx(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
    posfeats = [(featx(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

    negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
    poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

    trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
    testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]

    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
    refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

    for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testfeats):
            refsets[label].add(i)
            observed = classifier.classify(feats)
            testsets[observed].add(i)

    print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
    print 'pos precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
    print 'pos recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
    print 'neg precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
    print 'neg recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
    classifier.show_most_informative_features()

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

print 'evaluating single word features'
evaluate_classifier(word_feats)

word_fd = FreqDist()
label_word_fd = ConditionalFreqDist()

for word in movie_reviews.words(categories=['pos']):
    word_fd[word.lower()] += 1
    label_word_fd['pos'][word.lower()] += 1

for word in movie_reviews.words(categories=['neg']):
    word_fd[word.lower()] += 1
    label_word_fd['neg'][word.lower()] += 1

# n_ii = label_word_fd[label][word]
# n_ix = word_fd[word]
# n_xi = label_word_fd[label].N()
# n_xx = label_word_fd.N()

pos_word_count = label_word_fd['pos'].N()
neg_word_count = label_word_fd['neg'].N()
total_word_count = pos_word_count + neg_word_count

word_scores = {}

for word, freq in word_fd.iteritems():
    pos_score = BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq(label_word_fd['pos'][word],
        (freq, pos_word_count), total_word_count)
    neg_score = BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq(label_word_fd['neg'][word],
        (freq, neg_word_count), total_word_count)
    word_scores[word] = pos_score + neg_score

best = sorted(word_scores.iteritems(), key=lambda (w,s): s, reverse=True)[:10000]
bestwords = set([w for w, s in best])

def best_word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words if word in bestwords])

print 'evaluating best word features'
evaluate_classifier(best_word_feats)

def best_bigram_word_feats(words, score_fn=BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, n=200):
    bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(score_fn, n)
    d = dict([(bigram, True) for bigram in bigrams])
    d.update(best_word_feats(words))
    return d

print 'evaluating best words + bigram chi_sq word features'
evaluate_classifier(best_bigram_word_feats)
```

but now i get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\gerbuiker\Anaconda\python.exe E:/bigrams.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/bigrams.py", line 30, in <module>
    negfeats = [(bigram_word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
  File "E:/bigrams.py", line 24, in bigram_word_feats
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(score_fn, n)
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 112, in nbest
    return [p for p, s in self.score_ngrams(score_fn)[:n]]
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 108, in score_ngrams
    return sorted(self._score_ngrams(score_fn), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 100, in _score_ngrams
    score = self.score_ngram(score_fn, *tup)
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 169, in score_ngram
    return score_fn(n_ii, (n_ix, n_xi), n_all)
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\nltk\metrics\association.py", line 220, in chi_sq
    return n_xx * cls.phi_sq(n_ii, (n_ix, n_xi), n_xx)
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\nltk\metrics\association.py", line 212, in phi_sq
    ((n_ii + n_io) * (n_ii + n_oi) * (n_io + n_oo) * (n_oi + n_oo)))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Most code is coming from: http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/

and for the bigram case: http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/24/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-stopwords-collocations/

Comment: do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar situation and this is what I found. It's not so much about the script. It may be unique to my situation, still you may found it useful.

I break my text into sections to see if anything was causing the problem because I had a training data set that worked perfectly fine but my test data set gives this error message. In the end I found one line of text that's causing the problem, basically it's a sentence with exactly the same word, for example, "work work", or 'hello hello'.

Once I removed that line, the problem is gone. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this was what happened in my case. But I cannot drop that record so looking at alternative.

Comment: @SushantKulkarni still have issue, i remove duplicate sentence

Answer (score 0):

Hello the problem is here ou are not updating this line of code
`label_word_fd['pos'][word.lower()] += 1`
maybe you are trying to put a dict or a list where there it can take a single word after word, hope it helps

Try this maybe:
`for word in movie_reviews.words(categories=['neg']):
    print(word) #Put this line here and print ans whatch what is happening 
    word_fd[word.lower()] += 1
    label_word_fd['neg'][word.lower()] += 1`